# How to change the background color of form input when page loads?

Tags: javascript, forms, input

(I know I can do it directly with input style, but I have other intentions)

I tried several ways

```
<script> document.getElementById('myTextBox').style.backgroundColor = 'red'; </script>
<script> document.form1.myTextBox.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; </script>
```

I tried putting it on head, on body. I don't know what else to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use onload

```
<body onload="style()">
```

And put your code in a function, at the bottom of the body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function style(){
    document.getElementById('myTextBox').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Just putting the script at the end of body fixed it. I initially put it in the start of body. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the browser when to execute that statement in your case.
Putting it as a function call in the body's onload will do. 
Look at this example

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   function FooBarFunction()
   {
       document.getElementById('foo').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="FooBarFunction()">
<input type="textbox" id="foo">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(function(){
   $("#myTextBox").css("background","red");
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/8BnrF/

Comment: Document ready works after DOM is ready, if which there are many images or scripts to load, this will fail. $(window).load(function(){/*stuff*/}) would suit better.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by put your code in tag of body

```
<body >
   <script> document.getElementById('myTextBox').style.backgroundColor = 'red'; </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply put your scripts before this 
e.g ...

```
<script> document.form1.myTextBox.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or edit your script like this

```
<script>window.onload =function(){ document.getElementById('myTextBox').style.backgroundColor = 'red';

}
</script>
```